# Request to reopen question 689718

Tags: support, reopen-request

A while ago, I asked [this](https://superuser.com/q/689718/241659) question, which got marked as primarily opinion based.This is not an opinion-based question. This question is (clearly) asking why system RAM cannot have a battery backup in the same way as the CMOS and game-cartridges can.I have edited the question to make myself clear.Can it be reopened and answered ?

While there are some answers , there is a need for an  answer that would include some math and tech about how ( modern ) RAM functions (refresh cycles, etc..) and quantity (number of NAND cells, etc..) and an analysis of the power requirement of a battery to keep them alive and comparison to common (non-laptop) battery capacities.

Comment: System RAM *does* have a battery backup - Ever put your computer to sleep?

Comment: I am with @allquixotic. The aspects of the math and tech would be interesting, but there is old tech that has tried this  http://www.acard.com/english/fb0101.jsp?ino=28. There may be some  benchmark review sites. So system RAM can have a battery. Other wise, it seems you are asking "Why don't manufactures of motherboards put batteries on the board for potential RAM disk options?" Cost? Battery failure, damage to other components, redundancy requirements(See Acard, CF card) should non power time exceed battery expected duration from full charge? That is just how I see it.

Comment: @allquixotic post that as an answer, please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given enough time and resources, anything is possible. There is no physical, answerable, definite reason "why system RAM cannot have a battery backup". In my mind's eye, I can easily imagine a RAM chip with a battery mounted alongside it that would keep the RAM "warm" (operational) in event of power failure. See? It's possible. But it just isn't that way. The only reasons that exist are opinion-based reasons about why industry didn't go that way, etc. Therefore it is opinion-based. Recommend leaving it closed.